# How to overwrite a function in the web page with Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Suppose there is a web site has a global namespace `Q = {}`, and there is a function under it: `Q.foo`

I'd like to overwrite this function in my chrome extension, so when the web page calls `Q.foo`, it would do what I like.

I tried to write:

```
Q.foo = function(){
    alert("over written");
}
```

with content script. But it doesn't work....
thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The main problem iis that a chrome extension exists in a separated enviornment which was created so that extension developers cant screw with the existing page's javascript and vice versa.

However geeky people can do this:

```
document.head.innerHTML += '<script>Q.foo = function(){alert("over written");}</script>';
```

Basically what this does is that it appends a script tag into the dom which is then instantly eval'd in the context of the page.

Comment: This is not executing. Even a console.log doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Q.prototype.foo = function(){
  alert("over written");
}
```

Comment: I've looked at the .js files in the web page, foo is not binded on prototype, it's under Q directly

Comment: @wong2 in any case, this will over write the function for all instances of Q.

Comment: but Q is not a function, it's defined as Q = {};

Comment: i didnt meant Q as a function, i meant the function `foo`

Comment: I remember that if Q = {}, then Q has no property prototype.

Comment: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/

Comment: wong your right, Pheonix your getting _ _ proto _ _ and .prototype mixed up. Besides thats not what his problem is